# Pandas checks with prefix and more checksum if searched prefix exists or no data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have below code snippet which works fine.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

prefixes = ['sj00', 'sj12', 'cr00', 'cr08', 'eu00', 'eu50']
df = pd.read_csv('new_hosts', index_col=False, header=None)
df['prefix'] = df[0].str[:4]
df['grp'] = df.groupby('prefix').cumcount()
df = df.pivot(index='grp', columns='prefix', values=0)
df['sj12'] = df['sj12'].str.extract('(\w{2}\d{2}\w\*)', expand=True)
df = df[ prefixes ].dropna(axis=0, how='all').replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
df = df.rename_axis(None)
```

### Example File new_hosts

```
sj000001
sj000002
sj000003
sj000004
sj124000
sj125000
sj126000
sj127000
sj128000
sj129000
sj130000
sj131000
sj132000
cr000011
cr000012
cr000013
cr000014
crn00001
crn00002
crn00003
crn00004
euk000011
eu0000012
eu0000013
eu0000014
eu5000011
eu5000013
eu5000014
eu5000015
```

### Current output:

```
sj00        sj12        cr00        cr08        eu00        eu50
sj000001                cr000011    crn00001    euk000011   eu5000011
sj000002                cr000012    crn00002    eu0000012   eu5000013
sj000003                cr000013    crn00003    eu0000013   eu5000014
sj000004                cr000014    crn00004    eu0000014   eu5000015
```

### What's expected:

1) As code works fine but as you see the `current output` the second column don't have any values but still appearing So, how could i have a checksum if a particular column don't have any values then remove that from display.

2) Can we place a check for the `prefixes` if they exists in the dataframe before processing to avoid the error.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, before

```
df = df[ prefixes ].dropna(axis=0, how='all').replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
```

you can do:

```
# remove all empty columns
df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

That would solve your first part. Second part can be `reindex`?

```
# select prefixes:
prefixes = ['sj00', 'sj12', 'cr00', 'cr08', 'eu00', 'eu50', 'sh00', 'dt00', 'sh00', 'dt00']

df = df.reindex(prefixes, axis=1).dropna(axis=1, how='all').replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
```

Note the `axis=1`, not `axis=0` is identical to what I propose for question 1.

Comment: many thx Quang Hoang , i kept `axis=0` deliberately because  i want to remove all the empty row at the first chance.

Comment: `df` comes from `pivot`, so it is guaranteed that there are no empty rows.

Comment: indeed there are empty rows after `df` comes from `pivot`, in other words there are only 45 rows with data while it prints 135 so after 45 rows all are empty rows.

Comment: ah, then that must be something like the column `sj12` which has most counts, but then turned to `NaN`. In which case, you want to drop empty rows after converting `sj12`. You still need `dropna(axis=1)` after `reindex` to remove columns that are not in the original data, unless you want them there.

Comment: Do you have ay idea how to remove those blank rows.

Answer (score 0):

Much thanks to Quang Hoang for the hints on the post, Just for the workaround, i got it working as follows until i get a better answer:

```
# Select prefixes
prefixes = ['sj00', 'sj12', 'cr00', 'cr08', 'eu00', 'eu50']

df = pd.read_csv('new_hosts', index_col=False, header=None)

df['prefix'] = df[0].str[:4]

df['grp'] = df.groupby('prefix').cumcount()

df = df.pivot(index='grp', columns='prefix', values=0)

df = df[prefixes]

# For column `sj12` only extract the values having `sj12` and a should be a word immediately after that like `sj12[a-z]`
df['sj12'] = df['sj12'].str.extract('(\w{2}\d{2}\w\*)', expand=True)

df.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)

# Remove the empty columns
df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')

# again drop if all values in the row are nan and replace nan to empty for live columns
df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='all').replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)

# drop the index field
df = df.rename_axis(None)

print(df)
```